# Proving a general inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $a>0,b>0$ and $c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$.

Could you please help me to prove that $$\frac{a^2+b}{b+c}+\frac{b^2+c}{c+a}+\frac{c^2+a}{a+b}\ge 2$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h394701p2193659, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h5848p19390, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h496511p2788092.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your work along with the question

Comment: I showed that $\frac{a^2+b}{b+c}+\frac{b^2+c}{c+a}+\frac{c^2+a}{a+b}=\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{c+a}+\frac{c+a}{a+b}-(a+b+c) =\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{c+a}+\frac{c+a}{a+b}-1$. But I don't see how to show that $\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{c+a}+\frac{c+a}{a+b}\ge 3$.

Comment: @linaa5955 its AM_GM

Comment: what do you mean by AM_GM? Please

Comment: @linaa5955 $x+y+z\ge 3\sqrt[3]{xyz}$

Comment: i dont see how to use this inequality. could you please give more details

Comment: thank you I understand it now